# Simplifying and correct RSpec controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, bdd

I have a few RSpec controller tests.  Some work, some don't, and I'm trying to figure out how on Earth to fix them up and make them more efficient

Ideally, I would like to see if I can get each spec into the following form

```
subject { ... }
  it { ... }
  it { ... }
  it { ... }
```

Note that for all of my controller specs I've written macros for the actual controller actions.  The macros are all tested and all work, and the names make it fairly obvious what they do.

My "Create" test:

```
formats ||= ["html", "js"]
formats.each do |format|
  context "valid attributes" do
    subject { do_post_create( :customer, valid_attributes, format ) }
      its(:response_code) { should eq(302)}
      it { should redirect_to admin_customer_path(Customer.find_by_id(???))}
      it { expect { subject }.to change(Customer, :count).by(1) }
  end

  context "invalid attributes" do
    subject { do_post_create( :customer, invalid_attributes, format ) }
      its(:response_code) { should eq(200)}
      it { should render_template :new }
      it { expect { subject }.to_not change(Customer, :count).by(1) }
  end
end
```

In that spec, I've been trying to figure out some way to get the ID of the newly created object from the post statement.  I've tried "Customer.last", but that doesn't seem to work.  Any thoughts?

My "Update" spec:

```
formats ||= ["html", "js"]
formats.each do |format|
  context "valid attributes" do
    let(:object) { FactoryGirl.create(:customer) }
    subject { do_put_update( class_to_symbol(model), object.id, attributes, format ) }
      its(:response_code) { should eq(302)}

    it "does alter #{model}" do
      do_put_update( class_to_symbol(model), object.id, attributes, format )
      assigns(:customer).should eq(object)
      flash[:notice].should =~ /Success/
      object.reload
      attributes.each do |key, value|
        object.send(key.to_s).should eq(value)
      end
    end
  end
  context "invalid attributes" do
    let(:object) { FactoryGirl.create("customer") }
    let(:invalid_attributes) { {:username => "!"} }
    subject { do_put_update( class_to_symbol(model), object.id, invalid_attributes, format ) }
      its(:response_code) { should eq(200)}

    it "does not alter #{model}" do
      do_put_update( class_to_symbol(model), object.id, invalid_attributes, format )
      assigns(:customer).should eq(object)
      flash[:notice].should =~ /Fail/
      object.reload
      attributes.each do |key, value|
        object.send(key.to_s).should_not eq(value)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In the Update test, I would like to try to express the second block in a more concise way, ideally in a way that I can use the same "subject" statement for all of the tests.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're over-thinking these specs. Instead of trying to force every spec into a predefined format (`subject`/`it`/...) write the specs so that they clearly document what should happen, *then* try to refactor the code afterwards.

Case in point: the use of the implicit `subject` for controller actions. `subject` and `its` are meant to be used with an object, not a method, and only really make sense when used that way. So for example, this makes sense:

```
subject { [1, 2, 3, 4] }
its(:size) { should == 4 }
```

Here, it's absolutely clear what is being tested: a 4-element array has a size of 4.

However, when you write:

```
subject { do_post_create( :customer, valid_attributes, format ) }
its(:response_code) { should eq(302)}
```

it's not really clear where you are getting that response code from without inspecting the `do_post_create` action. You say that the names of the macros "make it fairly obvious what they do", but they don't make it fairly obvious *what they will return*, and this is key for using the implicit subject because it's the return value that becomes the subject.

It would be much clearer just to write:

```
it "responds with a 302" do
  do_post_create(:customer, valid_attributes, format)
  response.should eq(302)
end
```

I also don't recommend mixing specs with and without implicit subjects, since it makes it yet more confusing what you are actually testing. In your invalid attributes `context` block, for example, you set a subject, but then in your second spec you actually test assignment of `customer` (`assigns(:customer).should eq(object)`), so basically the subject is irrelevant for this test. (However by setting the subject here and then not using it you are actually sending a PUT request *twice* (through `do_put_update`), which is bound to cause problems -- again, another reason not to be making requests in a `subject` block.)

I could go on, but I think you get the picture. Making specs short and sweet is great if you can do it without hurting readability, but in this case I think you've gone overboard.

Just my two cents, hope it helps.

p.s. In case the views above seem a bit extreme, read the [documentation for implicit subjects](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-10/docs/subject/implicitly-defined-subject), where you'll see that they actually recommend against using implicit subjects at all in public-facing tests:

> While the examples below demonstrate how subject can be used as a user-facing concept, we recommend that you reserve it for support of custom matchers and/or extension libraries that hide its use from examples.

Comment: Hrm, those are very good points - consider me convinced.  As an aside, any thoughts on why "Customer.last" would be returning nil in my specs?